# Is there a way to feed single files one-by-one to a Jenkins job for it to act on those files?

Tags: file, jenkins, repository, bitbucket, pmd

I have a Jenkins Job that runs a PMD code analysis on java files in my bitbucket repository. Right now whenever it runs it acts on the whole repository which is too time consuming. Is there a way for me to feed the job one file after the other. So the job receives a file, acts on it, outputs the result, and moves onto the next file.

Right now the job is simply linked to my bitbucket repository using the link that I would give if trying to clone the repo. Someone suggested feeding file names to the job using the command line but I don't know how to do that.

Even if someone can guide me in having a Jenkins job run on a single file of my choosing that will help a lot

Comment: Are you using free style, scripted pipeline or declarative pipeline? Dou yo want to detect changes in one file instead the whole repository?

Comment: @JRichardsz I'm using a freestyle project and I want to detect the modified files on a pull request instead of the whole repo.

Comment: PMD can do incremental analysis, only checking for files that actually changed… you could enable it, and have your CI cache the analysis cache file to keep it between runs. Non-changed files from run to run will not even be analyzed by PMD.